# Can we do analytics on masking data using WEKA tool?

Tags: weka, data-masking

I just want to ask if there any possibilities to do analytics on masking data using the WEKA tool. In this case, not all data fields will be masking. Only a few of them.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by masking whether an attribute should be used by an algorithm for learning, then the answer is **yes** (in a sense).

However, rather than flagging attributes whether to be included or not, in Weka you'd simply **remove them**.

For example, for classification you would use the [FilteredClassifier](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) meta-classifier in conjunction with the actual base classifier that you want to use and the [Remove](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Remove.html) filter.

If you need additional filters to applied (e.g., Normalize), then simply define a filter pipeline using [MultiFilter](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html) as the filter in your FilteredClassifier setup. With that approach you can work with your original data and the base classifier only sees the data your filter pipeline outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answers! If you don't mind, can you explain more about the filter pipeline?

Comment: The MultiFilter simply combines several filters that get applied to the data one after the other, with the output data of one filter being the input data for the next one.